# box2d accelerometer how to make it work

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I'm trying to make the box2d accelerometer work, I have a car sprite and want it to move left and right, when the iPhone is tilted.

Here is the code for the sprite:

```
- (void)spawnCar {

car = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"car.jpg"];
car.position = ccp(160, 250);
car.tag = 2;

[self addBoxBodyForSprite:car];

[_spriteSheet addChild:car];

}
```

How can implement the accelerometer to work for left and right?

Answer (score 1):

Just do this...

in your init add

```
self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;
```

and then add this method...

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    b2Vec2 gravity(-acceleration.y * 15, acceleration.x *15);
    world->SetGravity(gravity);

}
```

Comment: but how do i make the actual sprite move?

Comment: @sahil you will have to get the body position and then update the sprite to match that location.  See the `tick` method available at http://www.raywenderlich.com/28602/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial-bouncing-balls